# I am getting an unexpected error while running an application (Lighting-Aura)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

Apex code-

```
public class Controller_Apex {
    @AuraEnabled
    Public static string callApexmtd(){
        return 'Amit kumar';
    }

}
```

---

component

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="Result" type="string" />
    <lightning:button label="submit" onclick="{!c.show}" />

</aura:component>
```

### controller:

```
({
    show : function(component, event, helper) {
        var abc=component.get("c.callApexmtd");
        abc.setcallback(this,function(response)
        {
        var state=response.getstate();
        console.log('state :' +state);
        if(state==='success'){
            var result=response.getreturnvalue();
            console.log('result' +result);
            component.set("v.result",result);
        }
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(abc);
}
})
```

### Application:

```
<aura:application extends="force.slds" >
    <c:component_apex />

</aura:application>
```

---

getting this error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Unable to
>   find action 'callApexmtd' on the controller of
>   Capita_one:component_apex Failing descriptor:
>   {Capita_one:component_apex}

Answer (score 4):

Your `<aura:component>` does not declare a `controller` attribute. You must explicitly declare which Apex class is serving as controller for this component so that the runtime can create controller instances and reference the appropriate methods.